# Can my landlord charge me a fee not stated in the lease? But told in text/verbally?

Tags: united-states, landlord, residential-lease, pennsylvania, utility-bills

This is in Pennsylvania.

My landlord told me, before I signed the lease, that there is a 45 dollar laundry fee every month. Ok, fine. I go to sighn the lease, and no where in the lease does it state that the fee is 45 bucks a month. Not to mention, my other roommates have either been told different prices, or have not been told about this fee at all. In fact, last month, no one paid the fee (except me and one other) and the landlord said nothing. I do not want to pay this fee if 1. I am the only one paying it and 2. If there is no way she can legally enforce this. After all, she only told me this over text and verbally...but not officially stated in the lease.

Thoughts?

Comment: How have you been paying for the fee? Just as part of your rent? If so, the landlord might have some room to claim that you've been paying for an agreed-upon increased rent, although generally, they are required to provide 30 days written notice before any increase in rent.